# Push Notification in DRF

Tags: python, django, push-notification, django-rest-framework

What should be exact and most appropriate method to implement push notifications in django rest framework. DRF documentation doesn't explain it well.
Help me out with this one

Comment: are u trying to implement ios and android push notification

Comment: yes @Zealous I was trying to do same.

Answer (score 6):

Django REST framework is for creating API in django using built in django functionalities to retrieve request and serve response.

Django by itself doesn't support any protocol that will allow push notifications to be sent to client, so DRF also won't do that.

To create push notifications you have to use websockets, there are some third-party packages adding support of websockets to django. One of them is [django-websocket-redis](https://github.com/jrief/django-websocket-redis)

Comment: I do agree that there are third-party packages and I've tried them and they are working fine , but what I was looking at was without using any of them.

Comment: There is no websocket support built-in, neither in django nor in DRF. If you don't want to use third-party package, you must write that support by yourself.

Comment: But python provides websocket support so it is possible to write one, I'm right.

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for push notification on the web (using web socket), you can try to use [Firebase Cloud messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client) (FCM, Firebase is [free](https://firebase.google.com/pricing/) with certain usage threshold). What you need is adding code to your django server to request Firebase to send notifications.

If you are looking for push notifications on mobile devices, [django-push-notifications](https://github.com/jleclanche/django-push-notifications) package looks good, it even provide support for DRF to keep track of devices. On Android, this will also use FCM as well.

Answer (score 3):

[django-push-notifications](https://github.com/jazzband/django-push-notifications) is the one you are looking for. It is simple and can be implemented with few lines of code. It can be used for all android, iOS and web push notifications.

Answer (score 0):

My Personal Favourite for this Purpose is: [Django Notification!](https://github.com/django-notifications/django-notifications) And [Django Pushy](https://github.com/rakanalh/django-pushy/blob/master/README.rst)!

Other Packages: [django-push-notifications](https://github.com/jazzband/django-push-notifications) [Django Activity Stream](https://github.com/justquick/django-activity-stream)

Try using the django-instapush package. It is easily available to install via pip. This support all sql databases and also mongoDB via mongoengine to store device information. It has built-in models that can be used to store device information so this will work out of the box. Here is a [little tutorial](https://techstricks.com/django-push-notifications-mongoengine/) on sending django push notifications using django instapush.

You can Also use:

https://pypi.org/project/django-sns-mobile-push-notification/

You can also try with some other push providers. [Infobip](https://www.infobip.com/en/platform/messaging/push) Push has some new things, for example you can track users by their locations and send push whenever they are apporaching some areas

Comment: Hello
Thanks a lot for your pieces of information. It's quite a lot of options. I am using django rest framework and sending email notification by using celery. 
Will you please guide me.
Which is the best choice among these for me. My database is MySQL.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to use WebSocket to implement your own notification, you can check out [channels](https://github.com/django/channels)

Comment: Your answer look more like a ad than like an answer. Check out this guide https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer and see if you can  add more to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you project DRF was structured without asynchronous process in mind. You can try out [django channels rest framework](https://github.com/hishnash/djangochannelsrestframework). you can easily pass asynch classes to you viewsets and make your endpoints behave like an asynchronous porcess.